# GTest not finding tests in separate compilation units

Tags: googletest

I've got a program written in C++, with some subfolders containing libraries linked in. There's a top level SConscript, which calls SConscript files in the subfolders/libraries.

Inside a library cpp, there is a GTest test function:

```
TEST(X, just_a_passing_test) {
EXPECT_EQ(true, true);
}
```

There is `main()` in the top level program source, which just calls GTests main, and has another GTest test within it:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}

TEST(Dummy, should_pass){
EXPECT_EQ(true, true);
}
```

Now the issue is that when I run the program, GTest only runs the test in the `main.cpp` source. Ignoring the test in the library. Now it gets bizarre when I reference an unrelated class in the same library cpp in `main.cpp`, in a no side-effect kind of way (eg. `SomeClass foo;`), the test magically appears. I've tried using -O0 and other tricks to force gcc to not optimize out code that isn't called. I've even tried Clang.
I suspect it's something to do with how GTest does test discovery during compilation, but I can't find any info on this issue. I believe it uses static initialization, so maybe there's some weird ordering going on there.
Any help/info is greatly appreciated!

**Update:** Found a section in the FAQ that sounds like this problem, despite it referring specifically to Visual C++. Which includes a trick/hack to force the compiler to not discard the library if not referenced.
It recommends not putting tests in libraries, but that leaves me wondering how else would you test libraries, without having an executable for every one, making quickly running them a pain and with bloated output.
https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer#Important_note_for_Visual_C++_users

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the scene-setting one gathers that the library whose `gtest` test case
goes missing is statically linked in the application build. Also that the
GNU toolchain is in use.

The cause of the problem behaviour is straightforward. The test 
program contains no references to anything in the library that contains 
`TEST(X, just_a_passing_test)`. So the linker doesn't *need* to link any 
object file from that library to link the program. So it doesn't. So the
`gtest` runtime doesn't find that test in the executable, because it's not there.

It helps to understand that a static library in GNU format is an archive
of object files, adorned with a house-keeping header block and a global symbol table.

The OP discovered that by coding in the program an *ad hoc* reference to
any public symbol in the problem library, he could "magically" compel its 
test case into the program.

No magic. To satisfy the reference to that public symbol, the linker is
now obliged to link an object file from the library - the one that contains
the definition of the symbol. And the OP imparts that the library is made
from a `.cpp`. So there is only one object file in the library, and it
contains the definition of the test case, too. With that object file in the
linkage, the test case is in program.

The OP twiddled in vain with the compiler options, switching from GCC to clang,
in search of a more respectable way to achieve the same end. The compiler is 
irrelevant. GCC or clang, it gets its linking done by the system linker, [`ld`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/)
(unless unusual measures have been taken to replace it).

Is there a more respectable way to get `ld` to link an object file from a
static library even when the program refers to no symbols in that object file?

There is. Say the problem program is `app` and the problem static library is
`libcool.a`

Then the usual GCC commandline that links `app` resembles this, in the relevant
points:

```
g++ -o app -L/path/to/the/libcool/archive -lcool
```

This delegates a commandline to `ld`, with additional linker options and
libraries that `g++` deems to be defaults for the system where it finds itself.

When the linker comes to consider `-lcool`, it will figure out this is a request
for the archive `/path/to/the/libcool/archive/libcool.a`. Then it will figure
out whether at this point it has still got any unresolved symbol references in hand
whose definitions are compiled in object files in `libcool.a`. If there are
any, then it will link those object files into `app`. If not, then it links
nothing from `libcool.a` and passes on.

But we know there are symbol definitions in `libcool.a` that we want to
link, even though `app` does not refer to them. In that case, we can tell
the linker to link the object files from `libcool.a` even though they are
not referenced. More precisely, we can tell `g++` to tell the linker to do that,
like so:

```
g++ -o app -L/path/to/the/libcool/archive -Wl,--whole-archive -lcool -Wl,-no-whole-archive
```

Those `-Wl,...` options tell `g++` to pass the options `...` to `ld`. The `--whole-archive`
option tells `ld` to link all object files from subsequent archives, whether they
are referenced or not, until further notice. The `-no-whole-archive` tells the
`ld` to stop doing that and resume business as usual.

It may look as if `-Wl,-no-whole-archive` is redundant, as it's the last thing on the
`g++` commandline. But it's not. Remember that `g++` appends system default libraries
to the commandline, behind the scenes, before passing it to the `ld`. You definitely
do not want `--whole-archive` to be in force when those default libraries are linked.
(The linkage will fail with multiple definition errors).

Apply this solution to the problem case and `TEST(X, just_a_passing_test)`
will be executed, without the hack of forcing the program to make some no-op 
reference into the object file that defines that test.

There's an obvious downside to this solution in the general case. If it happens that the library from
which we want to force linkage of some unreferenced object file contains a
bunch of other unreferenced object files that we *really* don't need.
`--whole-archive` links them all of them too, and they're just bloat in the program.

The `--whole-archive` solution may be more respectable that the no-op reference
hack, but it's not *respectable*. It doesn't even *look* respectable.

The real solution here is just to do the reasonable thing. If you want the 
linker to link the definition of something in your program, then *don't keep that a secret from
the linker.* At least *declare* the thing in each compilation unit where you
expect its definition to be used.

Doing the reasonable thing with `gtest` test-cases involves understanding that
a `gtest` macro like `TEST(X, just_a_passing_test)` expands to a *class definition*,
in this case:

```
class X_just_a_passing_test_Test : public ::testing::Test {
public: 
    X_just_a_passing_test_Test() {} 
private: 
    virtual void TestBody(); 
    static ::testing::TestInfo* const test_info_ __attribute__ ((unused)); 
    X_just_a_passing_test_Test(X_just_a_passing_test_Test const &); 
    void operator=(X_just_a_passing_test_Test const &);
};
```

(plus a static initializer for `test_info_` and a definition for `TestBody()`).

Likewise for the `TEST_F`, `TEST_P` variants. Consequently, you can deploy these
macros in your code with just the same constraints and expectations that would
apply to class definitions.

In this light, if you have a library `libcool` defined in `cool.h`, implemented in `cool.cpp`
and want `gtest` unit tests for it, to be executed by a test program `tests`
that is implemented in `tests.cpp`, the reasonable thing is:-

- Write a header file, `cool_test.h`
- `#include "cool.h"` in it
- `#include <gtest/gtest.h>` in it.
- Then define your `libcool` test cases in it
- `#include "cool_test.h"` in `tests.cpp`,
- Compile and link `tests.cpp` with `libcool` and `libgtest`

And it's obvious why you wouldn't do what the OP has done. You would not define
classes that are needed by `tests.cpp`, and *not* needed by `cool.cpp`, within `cool.cpp` 
and not in `tests.cpp`.

The OP was averse to the advice against defining the test cases in the library
because:

> how else would you test libraries, without having an executable for every one,
>    making quickly running them a pain.

As a rule of thumb I would recommend the practice of maintaining a `gtest` executable
per library to be unit-tested: running them quickly is painless with commonplace automation tools
such a `make`, and it's far better to get a pass/fail verdict per library than
just a verdict for a bunch of libraries. But if you don't want to do that there's still nothing to the
objection:

```
// tests.cpp
#include "cool_test.h"
#include "cooler_test.h"
#include "coolest_test.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Compile and link with `libcool`, `libcooler`, `libcoolest` and `libgtest`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. This helps confirm my suspicions. In the end I used executable targets for each library to run the unit tests.

Comment: In my case helped in Xcode change from Static library to Relocatable Object file in Mach-O type

Comment: I forgot to remove -static from CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, now it works just as https://github.com/anastasiak2512/Calendar

Comment: Thanks for the detail info. But I don't understand when you say define (you probably meant declare) the `libcool` test cases in the header file `cool_test.h`.  The macros `TEST` and `TEST_F` are used to **both** declare and define (implement) your tests. Is there another macro that will return only the declaration (signature) of a test case or test fixture ?

Comment: "As a rule of thumb I would recommend the practice of maintaining a gtest executable per library to be unit-tested" -- this, exactly. For some reason I had decided to try to create a single test exe, but this is the wrong direction.